# Creating Polyline shapefile from text file using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geometry

I'm trying to create a polyline shapefile from a text file which provides `Name, coordX, coordY`.  I've created the following script, which I feel will work. However, I can't seem to get it to read the text file properly. I am getting the following error, `RuntimeError: Object: CreateObject cannot create geometry from inputs.`

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Data"

outFolder = "C:\\Data"
fc = "Paths.shp"

spatRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(26913)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outFolder, fc, "POLYLINE", "", "", "", spatRef)

coordinateList = open("C:\\Data\\Paths.txt")

for line in coordinateList.readlines():
    print line

pointList = arcpy.Array()

for x, y in coordinateList:
    point = arcpy.Point(x,y)
    pointList.add(point)

polyline = arcpy.Polyline(pointList)

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, "SHAPE@")
cursor.insertRow([polyline])

del cursor
```

Comment: I think you need to split your line, you indents are funny but it looks like you need to use LineSplit = line.split(',') to break up into a list then set x = LineSplit[1] and y = LineSplit[2] (name is LineSplit[0]) but I can't be sure. Can you include the first 10 lines of your text file as an example please and fix the indenting of the code block so it matches what you have in your code.

Comment: The code above is indented properly from what I can tell and reads like it should and does in my script.

Comment: It is preferable to edit those into your question rather than add each line as comments. Does the Name change? if so does the change of name make a new polyline?

Comment: FredRanch1_1, 529018.125025, 4108038.05548
FredRanch1_1, 529005.718792, 4108028.20659
FredRanch1_1, 528993.340503, 4108018.73931
FredRanch1_1, 528980.990158, 4108009.65364
FredRanch1_1, 528968.667757, 4108000.94958
FredRanch1_1, 528956.373301, 4107992.62713
FredRanch1_1, 528944.106788, 4107984.68629
FredRanch1_1, 528931.86822, 4107977.12705
FredRanch1_1, 528919.657595, 4107969.94943
FredRanch1_1, 528907.474915, 4107963.15341

Comment: FredRanch1_2, 529018.125025, 4108038.05548
FredRanch1_2, 528994.381279, 4108036.02086
FredRanch1_2, 528971.341496, 4108034.79222
FredRanch1_2, 528949.005677, 4108034.36954
FredRanch1_2, 528938.101754, 4108034.46044
FredRanch1_2, 528927.373822, 4108034.75283
FredRanch1_2, 528916.82188, 4108035.24671
FredRanch1_2, 528906.44593, 4108035.94208
FredRanch1_2, 528896.24597, 4108036.83895
FredRanch1_2, 528886.222001, 4108037.93731

Comment: FredRanch1_3, 529018.125025, 4108038.05548
FredRanch1_3, 529007.420422, 4108054.08101
FredRanch1_3, 528997.143145, 4108070.21006
FredRanch1_3, 528987.293193, 4108086.44262
FredRanch1_3, 528977.870566, 4108102.7787
FredRanch1_3, 528968.875266, 4108119.21829
FredRanch1_3, 528960.30729, 4108135.7614
FredRanch1_3, 528952.16664, 4108152.40802
FredRanch1_3, 528944.453316, 4108169.15816
FredRanch1_3, 528937.167317, 4108186.01181

Comment: Yes, the name changes quite a few times.  I'm guessing it does make a new polyline for each name

Comment: That makes it a bit more complicated, does the name get inserted into the output shapefile?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84667/discussion-on-question-by-jack-jenkins-creating-polyline-shapefile-from-text-fil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest edit to make your code work:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Data"
outFolder = "C:\\Data"
fc = "Paths.shp"

spatRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(26913)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outFolder, fc, "POLYLINE", "", "", "", spatRef)

coordinateList = open("C:\\Data\\Paths.txt")

pointList = arcpy.Array()
for line in coordinateList.readlines():
    print line

    SplitLine = line.split(',') # break up the string into elements
    # 'FredRanch1_1, 529018.125025, 4108038.05548' becomes
    # ['FredRanch1_1', '529018.125025', '4108038.05548'] which can be indexed
    x = float(SplitLine[1]) # turn the strings into numbers
    y = float(SplitLine[2])

    point = arcpy.Point(x,y)
    pointList.add(point)

polyline = arcpy.Polyline(pointList)

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, "SHAPE@")
cursor.insertRow(polyline)

del cursor
coordinateList.close() # don't forget to close your file
```

Using with statements condenses the code and ensures you don't forget to free the cursor and close the file:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Data"
outFolder = "C:\\Data"
fc = "Paths.shp"

spatRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(26913)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outFolder, fc, "POLYLINE", "", "", "", spatRef)

with open("C:\\Data\\Paths.txt",'r') as coordinateList:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,'SHAPE@') as cursor:
        pointList = arcpy.Array()
        for line in coordinateList:
            SplitLine = line.split(',') # break up the string into elements
            # 'FredRanch1_1, 529018.125025, 4108038.05548' becomes
            # [FredRanch1_1, 529018.125025, 4108038.05548] which can be indexed
            x = float(SplitLine[1])
            y = float(SplitLine[2])

            point = arcpy.Point(x,y)
            pointList.add(point)
    cursor.insertRow(polyline)
```

With the added complication of starting a new line when the name changes:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Data"
outFolder = "C:\\Data"
fc = "Paths.shp"

spatRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(26913)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outFolder, fc, "POLYLINE", "", "", "", spatRef)
arcpy.AddField_management(fc,'Name','TEXT',field_length=250)

oldName = None
pointList = arcpy.Array()
with open("C:\\Data\\Paths.txt",'r') as coordinateList:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,['SHAPE@','Name']) as cursor:
        for line in coordinateList:
            SplitLine = line.split(',') # break up the string into elements
            # 'FredRanch1_1, 529018.125025, 4108038.05548' becomes
            # ['FredRanch1_1', '529018.125025', '4108038.05548'] which can be indexed
            if oldName == None:
                oldName = SplitLine[0] # only should happen on the first iteration

            x = float(SplitLine[1]) # turn the strings into numbers
            y = float(SplitLine[2])

            if oldName.upper() != SplitLine[0].upper():
                # the name has changed!
                polyline = arcpy.Polyline(pointList)
                cursor.insertRow([polyline,oldName]) # insert this line on name change
                pointList = arcpy.Array()            # reset the array
                oldName = SplitLine[0]               # make this name the old name

            point = arcpy.Point(x,y)
            pointList.add(point)
    polyline = arcpy.Polyline(pointList)
    cursor.insertRow([polyline,oldName]) # clean up the last line
```

**Caveat** I have not tested this code, it's from a copy of some of my existing code to do a similar purpose... I may have deleted a necessary line or neglected to change a variable name.

Comment: Okay, while this worked to an extent.  It did no create multiple lines.  it created on big crazy jumbled line.  How do I get it to create separate lines?

Comment: I have edited in the new code @JackJenkins. It's from a script I wrote to turn POS information (very similar to GPS) into a *line of travel*, though in that script I used the distance between vertices to break the lines (more than 100 metres made a new line), hopefully the changes I've made are bug free.

Comment: cursor.insertRow([polyline, oldName])
NameError: name 'polyline' is not defined

Comment: I'm guessing that polyline is referring to 'fc'...yes?

Comment: doh! I'll fix that now. A fumble in the edit.. the original generated the polyline on insert like: cursor.insertRow([arcpy.Polyline(pointList),oldName]) but when I changed the code to match your variable names I forgot to instantiate the polyline object.

Comment: I'm still getting errors mate.  The first option you provided, made one single line encompassing all the text file.  The 2nd option, created some random line.  I'm not sure how that works.  Any advice?

Comment: Try the 3rd option, it's the only one that allows for new lines for new names. I have modified the code to create the polyline prior to insert. See if that works for you. You will get an error if there is only one point in the name; this code assumes that instances of name are sorted, it will not go back to an existing line and extend it - you should be able to sort the CSV in Excel if the names are non-contiguous.